# Struts2 Convention plugin doesn't scan Action classes

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

Project structure
[image: Project structure]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorldAction.java

```
package com.example.web.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello from HelloWorldAction class!");
        setMessage("Hello World!");
        return super.execute();
    }
}
```

hello-world.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World JSP</title>
</head>
<body>

This is message ${message}

</body>
</html>
```

When I link to /hello-world I see only "This is message" text but there is no value of ${message}. Also the console doesn't show message by System.out.println(). Hence, HelloWorldAction doesn't call. What do I do wrong?
P.S. I'm using struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16.3.

After plugging of log4j and viewing of logs this trouble was solved. There wasn't asm libraries at my classpath.
[image: classpath]

Comment: Are you sure it's not passing through the Action ? Put a log in there and check it out. Also try using `This is message <s:property value="message"/>` in JSP, by obviously adding the JSP directive to match the `s` prefix to `struts-tags` at the top of the JSP

Comment: There wasn't asm libraries at my classpath therefore it didn't work. Thank you very much @AndreaLigios for tip with logging.